# CSS floating list items

Tags: html, css, list, internet-explorer-8

in reference to this http://alistapart.com/d/multicolumnlists/example1.html, I am wonder if there is a non-js option to float list item one by one underneath each other, with multiple list. I try everything from float/clear to inline-block, but I can't get it to work. it must work with ie8 and up.

[image]

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  /*must have set height*/
  background: lightgreen;
  /*so we can see our div boundry*/
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  /*put list side by side*/
}
li {
  /* try float: left; didn't work */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>FAILED</h1>
  <ul>
    <h2>ONE</h2>
    <li>List Items</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <h2>TWO</h2>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <h2>Three</h2>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is use the [`column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) property just if you can handle the [`support`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

```css
div {
  height: 190px;
  width:400px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <h2>ONE</h2>
    <li>List Items</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <h2>TWO</h2>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <h2>Three</h2>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
    <li>List Items</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really need a ie8 up option.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add the following CSS:

```
ul {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will align all lists at the top instead of the bottom.

Comment: I don't think this is what I ask for, but thanks anyway.